# ¿Cómo hago para tomar los datos de un prompt y usar if en este?

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones, while

Apena sé usar HTML y tengo una tarea sobre: "Ingrese N datos", el programa debe decir cuántos números son pares y cuántos son impares. Pero no sé realmente cómo funciona JavaScript y tengo que utilizar `while` y `if` sí o sí en el código.

```
function mostrar() {
  var cantidad = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('numero')[0].value);
  var arraydato = [cantidad];
  var x = 0;

  while(x < cantidad) {
      var contenum = prompt('ingrese numeros a comprobar' + x);
      arraydato[x] = contenum;     
      x++;
  }

  var promedio = parseFloat(suma / cantidad);
  document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = promedio;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

tu código casi casi hace lo que tu pides.

Lo que necesita este código es que en el HTML de la página donde se aloja este javascript - que no java :) - tenga un elemento tipo input que se llame 'numero'.

Ademas en lugar de hallar el promedio tienes que contar los pares.

Una solución solo javascript podría ser:

```
function pares(){
    var cantidad =  prompt('¿Cuantos numeros quiere comprobar?');
    // nos aseguramos que es un múmero
    if( isNaN(cantidad) ){
        alert("NO es un número " + cantidad);
        return;
    }
    var arraydato =[];
    var x = 1;

    pares = 0;
    while(x<=cantidad){
        var contenum = prompt('Ingrese el numero ' + x + ' a comprobar');
        if( isNaN(contenum ) ){
            alert("NO es un número " + contenum);
            return;
        }
        if( contenum % 2 == 0 ) pares++;
        x++;
    }

    let msg = ' son pares ';
    if( pares == 1 ) msg = ' es par ';

    alert("De " + cantidad + ' numeros, '  + pares + msg);
}
```

Un primer prompt tomaría el número de números a comprobar, y el bucle iría luego tomando los números uno a uno y comprobando si en resto (modulo usando el operador %) es igual a 0 al dividir entre dos, lo que lo identificaría como par.